# Add Timestamp if row is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script on a nightly trigger which does the following three things:

1. copies the contents of one spreadsheet (spreadsheet 1) to another (spreadsheet 2).
2. adds a timestamp column to column A each time the script is run.
3. deletes rows if there are certain values in column D.

The first time the script runs, everything works fine (i.e. when the new spreadsheet 2 is still blank).  The subsequent times it runs it encounters issues.

With some research I have discovered that is because any blank rows in the source sheet (spreadsheet 1) are copied to the new spreadsheet (spreadsheet2) and a timestamp is placed in the blank rows. This leaves a bunch of rows that only have a timestamp. By the time the script gets to the part where it is supposed to delete rows based on values it gets thrown by these rows that only have a timestamp.

I am new to google script and was unable to find anything in the forum. Is there a way to modify the script so that the timestamp is only placed on rows where there is data?

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "spreadsheet1 ID";
var sourceWorksheetName = "BusinessDetails";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "spreadsheet2 ID";
var targetWorksheetName = "Sheet5";

function importBusinessDetailsData(){
    var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet1 ID");
    var thisWorksheet   = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("BusinessDetails");
    var thisData        = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();

    var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet2 ID");
    var toWorksheet   = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet5");
    var toRange       = toWorksheet.getRange(1,2, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())

    toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues());

    setTimeStamp()
    main()
    removeThenSetNewVals()
}

function setTimeStamp() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet5')
    .getRange('A2:A').setValue(new Date())
};

function main() {
    var startTime          = new Date().getTime();
    var deleteSelectedRows = removeThenSetNewVals();
    var runTime            = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;

    Logger.log("Runtime is: " + runTime + " seconds");
};

function removeThenSetNewVals(){

    var sheet          = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet5');
    var range          = sheet.getDataRange();
    var pattern        = new RegExp("value1|value2|value3"); 
    var columnToSearch = 3;
    var newRangeVals   = range.getValues().filter(r => r[0] && !pattern.exec(r[columnToSearch]))  

    range.clearContent();

    var numRows  = newRangeVals.length;
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, numRows, newRangeVals[0].length).setValues(newRangeVals);
    var maxRows  = sheet.getMaxRows();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you only want to write entries to the new sheet which fit a particular condition. Basically, you want to `filter` the records before you write them, therefore consider the following:

```
var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
var rowsWithData = thisData.filter( row => row[3] )
```

This states that only rows which contain truthy data will be considered, but feel free to fit the condition according to your needs.

#### References

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: Thank you.  I will try and figure out how to add this in.  I have a few follow up questions.  What does the 3 refer to in the second line you suggested?  Is there a way to use this filter to only bring in rows that have certain values in column D?   This would eliminate the need for trying to isolate only rows with values and it would eliminate the last portion of the script which deletes rows after they have been copied over.

Comment: 3 refers to the index of that particular row, i.e. Column A = Column 1 = Column Index 0, Column B = Column 2 = Column Index 1, and so on. Therefore the third index is column D. Basically, the function states that only rows where column d is truthy are added to the `rowsWithData` variable.

Comment: Thank you.  This took care of it!